# Mysql | Change the location of the databases folder

Tags: hp-ux, mysql

I have a HP-UX server with two instances of Mysql.

1. The first one was the original and was located in `/mysql`, and keeps its database files in `/mysql/data/`
2. The second one I have installed by mistake and is located in `/usr/local/mysql`, and it keeps its database files in `/usr/local/mysql/data/`

Now the problem is (i guess because of the new installation), when i issue the command to start the mysql daemon (the original one located in `/mysql`) i receive the following message:

[image]

... so as you can see I start the daemon from the **old** instance of mysql but when it starts it is now using the **new** installation database files.

How can i change the path (what file i should edit) in order to make the daemon to point to the old database files that are located in `/mysql/data/`?

Comment: Did you try to change datadir directive on mysql config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000) should answer your question. it describes how mysql reads configuration files.  It looks like you will need two users for mysql to run two instances from two different locations.

Comment: thanks for the link.. there is some great explanations there.. I'll see what I can do tomorrow and will post some feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an option to mysqld
here is the link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/mysqld-safe.html

so, just start mysqd-safe script with --datadir=your_path option :

```
    #/mysql/bin/mysqld-safe --datadir=/mysql/data
```

Comment: hmmm.. i didn't know that.. I will try this as soon as I get back to work tomorrow :)

Comment: Yup.. that did it :). By using the `--datadir` flag I was able to verify and force the daemon to use the database files located in `/mysql/data` folder. However by using the info link provided by @Chris Drappier I was able to correctly solve my problem.